# Read more numbers in a line in Python

Tags: python, user-input

Let say i want to read the integers a, b and c from stdin (in one line, do not need to press return after each number). In c++, i would just do:

cin >> a >>b >> c;

How to do this in Python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
values = raw_input()
# 1 3 15
a, b, c = values.split()
```

`a` will be `'1'`, `b` will be `'3'` and `c` will be `'15'`.

---

If you want to be extra short and get ints try this:

```
a, b, c = [int(_) for _ in raw_input().split()]
```

Comment: They'll be strings, not ints.

Comment: Note that `raw_input` is the recommended one for Python 2. So much so, that it is now spelled `input` in Python 3 (and the old Python 2 `input` is gone). http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/

Answer (score 3):

for string

```
a,b,c=raw_input().split()
```

for int

```
a,b,c=map(int,raw_input().split())
```